# Flash not working in Firefox 10.0 after update

Tags: firefox, flash

As the title says after updating Firefox to 10.0 the other day the flash player has stopped working.

I keep getting the flash is missing error and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times without luck. I also tried running firefox with all addons disabled again without any luck.

Flash works fine in IE9 however.

Anyone who can help me get flash working again? :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easist to re-install the flash from firefox to automate the reload of the app:
[adobe - flash player download](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)